# Curved border on one side still shows thin line on the other sides when background is transparent, ONLY in mobile - why does this happen?

Tags: css

Lately, I've gotten into making CSS art and I noticed something that I don't understand about CSS borders.

If I style an element to be rounded with a transparent background, and set a border on only one side, there's still a faint line on all the other sides that shows up **only on mobile**.

```
<div></div>

div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background: transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid purple;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Compare the following CodePen on a PC vs phone to see what I mean:

https://codepen.io/aradevich/pen/mdrLvqx

Screenshot:
[ellipse with 5px top border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmjz7.jpg)

This effect is particularly bothersome when it skews facial features in CSS art, like with the eyes here on mobile: https://codepen.io/aradevich/pen/qBaxQye?editors=1100

Does anyone know why this happens, and how I can address it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a different idea to have the same result without the border issue:

```css
div.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background: 
    /*  150 = width/2   70 = height/2 - 5px of border */
    radial-gradient(151px 70px at bottom, transparent 98%,purple) 
    top/100% 50% no-repeat;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far I know, maybe it's caused by browser rendering. So, the solution is change the graphic image to SVG or PNG instead of css.